# How to use setqflist to add an entry to the quickfix list

Tags: quickfix

I'd like to be able to define my own functions that add certain kinds of line to the quickfix list, or set it to those in its entirety, without having to go via the filesystem with a made-up `errorfile` format that I tell vim how to parse (`errorfmt`).

I've seen `setqflist` and `getqflist`, but the only other questions or discussion I've seen about this has been people wanting to remove entries, and so the answer ends up being `filter` - which doesn't tell me how to format an entry if I want to *add* one.

So, if I'm to call `setqflist(my_errs)`, how should I define `my_errs`?

Answer (score 2):

`getqflist()` and `setqflist()` are sort of opposites. Printing out the results of `getqflist()` will give you and idea of the structure `setqflist()` is looking for.

```
call setqflist(getqflist())
```

Recent versions of Vim (8+) also allow you to use `lines` & `efm` to parse a list of lines with a different format than the current `'errorformat'`.

For more information see `:h setqflist()` & `:h getqflist()`

Answer (score 1):

I have this function. 
The format of setloclist is the same as of setqflist. 
Hope you find it helpful.

You need to set in the argument action 'a' for add.

```
function! Matches(pat)
let buffer=bufnr("") "current buffer number
let b:lines=[]
"the right way to escape!!
execute ":%g/\\V" . escape(a:pat,'/\?') . "/let b:lines+=[{'bufnr':" . 'buffer' . ", 'lnum':" . "line('.')" . ", 'text': escape(getline('.'),'\"')}]"
"call setloclist(0, [], ' ', {'items': b:lines}) 
call setloclist(0,b:lines)
lopen
endfunction
```